# PostgreSQL request taking a lot of time to sum 30 columns

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've an interesting case, I've been able to solve it but in a strange way.
Here's my request :

```
WITH geom_cte as (SELECT geom as geom)
SELECT SUM(number_a * percentage) AS number_a,
       ...
       SUM(number_b * percentage) AS number_b,
       SUM(number_z * percentage) AS number_z
FROM table_a AS A
JOIN (
  SELECT percentage, some_id
  FROM table_c, geom_cte
  WHERE postgis_indexed_condition
) AS B
ON B.some_id = A.some_id
```

There are 30 sums. This request takes 12s, which is a lot.
Here's the explain analyze : https://explain.depesz.com/s/L0aN

```
Aggregate  (cost=194.57..194.58 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=11997.284..11997.287 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=25409
  CTE cte
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..40.41 rows=17 width=3307) (actual time=0.354..247.066 rows=740 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=3368
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..25.68 rows=17 width=2325) (actual time=0.341..235.795 rows=740 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1145
              ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using forme_iris_geography_idx on forme_iris iris  (cost=0.28..25.64 rows=2 width=2293) (actual time=0.336..235.110 rows=740 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((geometry)::geography && cte.circle)
                    Filter: (_st_distance((geometry)::geography, cte.circle, '0'::double precision, false) < '1e-05'::double precision)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 97
                    Buffers: shared hit=1145
        ->  Index Scan using dl_rawdata_recensement_pkey on dl_rawdata_recensement population  (cost=0.29..0.87 rows=1 width=1002) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=740)
              Index Cond: ((iris)::text = (iris.code_iris)::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=2223
Planning Time: 1.677 ms
Execution Time: 11997.822 ms
```

It was quite strange because it take nearly a second to retrieve all the rows without the aggregation.
That's why I've decided to wrap the first result without aggregation in a cte and then aggregate in a second time. Surprisingly, the request now takes 700ms.

```
WITH geom_cte as (SELECT geom as geom),
data as (
SELECT number_a,
       number_b,
       ...
       number_z,
       percentage
FROM table_a AS A
JOIN (
  SELECT percentage, some_id
  FROM table_c, geom_cte
  WHERE postgis_indexed_condition
) AS B
ON B.some_id = A.some_id)
SELECT SUM(number_a * percentage) as number_a,
       SUM(number_b * percentage) as number_b,
       ...
       SUM(number_z * percentage) as number_z
FROM data
```

2nd explain analyze : https://explain.depesz.com/s/Z893

```
Aggregate  (cost=49.56..49.57 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=591.248..591.250 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4079
  CTE cte
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE data
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..45.26 rows=17 width=1010) (actual time=1.114..582.267 rows=740 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4079
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..25.68 rows=17 width=2325) (actual time=0.322..218.904 rows=740 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=1145
                ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                ->  Index Scan using forme_iris_geography_idx on forme_iris iris  (cost=0.28..25.64 rows=2 width=2293) (actual time=0.319..218.670 rows=740 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((geometry)::geography && cte.circle)
                      Filter: (_st_distance((geometry)::geography, cte.circle, '0'::double precision, false) < '1e-05'::double precision)
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 97
                      Buffers: shared hit=1145
          ->  Index Scan using dl_rawdata_recensement_pkey on dl_rawdata_recensement population  (cost=0.29..0.87 rows=1 width=1002) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=740)
                Index Cond: ((iris)::text = (iris.code_iris)::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=2223
  ->  CTE Scan on data  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=17 width=1000) (actual time=1.117..583.875 rows=740 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4079
Planning Time: 1.021 ms
Execution Time: 591.435 ms
```

Any idea about why making the aggregation directly is that much costly ?

PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 11.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit

PostGIS version: 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: The explain plan really needs to be inside the Question. If you wait for folks to follow links to help you, you're going to increase the wait time.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've edited my post.

Comment: Using multiple tables in the FROM is so SQL92 -- Use JOIN instead.  And the expression `postgis_indexed_condition` is probably significant.

Comment: I don't think that the condition is significant. As I said, I'm able to retrieve the correct rows (without aggregation) in really short time. Furthermore, it would still not be able to run fast in the second case.

Comment: This seems more like a PostgreSQL-centric [dba.se] issue

Comment: Ok, I'll repost it then.